# how to handle javascript loading error in web application which uses facebook javascript sdk

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am integrating a web application with facebook by following [this tutorial](http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/new-javascript-sdk-oauth-2-0-based-fbconnect-tutorial/)

It is normally working but when AVG do not track is active the browser can't load the Facebook JavaScript SDK so I want to show the user that in such a case he needs to disable the AVG do not track for the current website..

Is there a way to handle the loading error in JavaScript? We have try catch in Java - is there something similar in JavaScript so that I can hadle the loading error.

Sorry if this is a simple question ... I am a noob when it comes to JavaScript :(

Comment: Where does the error show up when AVG is active?  (Does `fbAsyncInit` never fire or does it error out further into the code?)

Comment: I think the async function is firirng but the donot track is not allowing the facebook js to load

Comment: it shows the following in the console  GET http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js  http://www.navaneet.opilane.com/:84
(anonymous function) http://www.navaneet.opilane.com/:84
(anonymous function)

Comment: try `cookie: false` in FB.init

Comment: doesn't work..i tried that :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I attached a little function to give feedback at the end of the code supplied by the tutorial.

http://jsfiddle.net/PRvJs/1/

The problem is that because your script is running in a web app and the blocking is happening on the browser application level, you can only ever infer that things have gone awry, and even then you have to make assumptions – scripts have `load` and `error` events but most Facebook blocking scripts circumvent that whole thing and just kill the HTTP request before it even goes out… so you can never really know!

As a fallback, I made the subjective decision to wait 30 seconds and if there is still no `load` or `error` resolution to the script injection, makes the arbitrary [1] decision that something is fundamentally screwed somewhere between your code and Facebook. As far as I know, this is the most you can determine and the only way to determine it…

[1] Most connections close if nothing has happened in 30 seconds.

Comment: Try loading the link, and activating your plugin… Basically one of those three events will always fire. But from my experimentation with Facebook blocker plugins, or networks where Facebook is blocked, basically the HTTP connection is interrupted and you can only infer this from receiving nothing after 30s.